# I want to know what I'm doing wrong with my code

Tags: macos, bash-scripting

Code

```bsh
removeapp(){
hi=1
while 'expr ${hi] <= $#'; do {
c="${c} $(${hi})"
hi='
}
sudo rm -rf '/applications/$c.app'
}
```

This is code to delete any app.
The idea is that the $c adds up the arguments into one variable and therefore one string of text.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I see a few questionable things:

1. On line 3 you have `${hi]` which doesn't seem right. You probably wanted a closing curly bracket, not a square bracket.
2. On line 4, you're executing the value of `$hi` in a subshell. `$hi` currently expands to `1`, so you're trying to execute the command `1` in a subshell, and use its stdout. Well, `1` isn't a command most shells would recognize, so that's probably not what you meant to do.
3. On line 5, you start a single-quote string but leave it open, which probably isn't what you meant to do.
4. On line 7, you have `$c` inside a single-quote string, so it won't be expanded; it'll just be left as a literal `$c`. This probably isn't what you meant to do.

Answer (score 1):

A few things in addition to Spiff’s answer:

5. The `while` keyword should be followed by an ordinary command. 
   `'ls -l'` and `'grep somename /etc/passwd'`
   (typed *with* the quotes) won’t work; neither will `'expr ${hi] <= $#'`. 
   Leave off the quotes.
6. Unless you are using some monstrously old shell,
   you don’t need to use `expr` to do simple comparisons. 
   Just use the shell’s `[`…`]` construct. 
   (But you will need to change the syntax of the test.)
7. You don’t need to use `{` and `}` to delimit a loop. 
   (You *can* use them, but you don’t need to here.) 
   But, when you use `while`,
   you must start the loop with `do` and end it with `done`.
8. You are setting `c` in terms of itself. 
   That’s OK, but you never initialize it. 
   You could be adding to a previously-set value.
9. `$(${hi})` is the wrong syntax to refer to a positional parameter.
10. To “add up” all the parameters, you don’t need to go to all that work;
    just say `c="$*"`.
11. But your whole approach is wrong. 
    If you fixed everything, and then you said

    ```
    removeapp dog elk fox
    ```

    it would do

    ```
    sudo rm -rf "/applications/dog elk fox.app"
    ```

    which isn’t what you want. 
    Think your problem all the way through.
12. Please indent your code properly.